# Multiple foreign keys in parent records (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, has-many-through

I'm trying to get rid of my join tables, in favor of a database design that is faster for large datasets. The way I'm planning to do this is to store the id's of children in the parent record.
Like so:

**Parents table:**
id, child1_id, child2_id, child3_id,... child(100)_id

**Children table:**
id, grandchild1_id, grandchild2_id,... grandchild(100)_id

**models:**
Parent
has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
Child
belongs_to :parent
has_many :grandchildren, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandchildren
Grandchild
belongs_to :child

My end result would be to be able to edit parent, children and grandchildren in the same form. This is already possible by using join tables, but I'm keen on boosting up performance

How can I get better performance for my database, when I depend on the functionality join tables provides?
Please help, I've been searching the web for many days now :/ Thanks!

Comment: This is a terrible design. Whilst it may speed up read/write for one case, it limits it to that - not only that, but, its not normal. Surely a non-relational database would be better if this really is your aim.

Comment: Arsen: I updated my post with a question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible database design. What if a parent has more than 100 children? 
3 suggestions:

- Consider using NOSQL database store.
- Perhaps use acts_as_tree.
- Could you not normalize it as such:

Parent: id

Child: id, parent_id

Grandchild: id, child_id

Comment: Well, I must agree it's not a very good design in general. When it comes to how many children a parent can have I already have set a maximum. It's not a problem for my app, though in general it would be terrible.

The example you provide is good while the Parent table doesn't contain information about the Child table. I'm going to give you a better example of the Parent Table:

Parent: id, child1_id, child1_attribute1, child1_attribute2, child2_id ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a problem with performance? If you are only anticipating, you may be doing premature optimization.

If you are able to create this many columns as the number of children, then I am almost sure that the database design which you are trying to avoid, is not the problem. Just ensure that the database has proper indexes.

A working (and covered by tests) application is a good starting point for thinking about performance. It may happen that you notice that the performance is acceptable with the simplest approach.

Comment: For my application. If I start with one parent, I'll end up with something like 20+ children, with additional 200+ grandchildren. Now say I have 10 000 parents, that will give me 2 000 000+ grandchildren. 2 000 000 grandchildren means 2 000 000+ join records for the server to go through every time I lookup 1 parent.
Is this not a problem? I'm asking because I really don't know. If the answer is 'NO' and you're sure about it then you really saved my day :)

Comment: Well, I am not sure, but you may try the simplest solution. I had some situations, when my fears proved to be false, and the simplest approach worked.

Comment: About the numbers: if a parent has 20 children, and each child has 20 grandchildren, it gives only 400+ records for a single modified object (one parent). A properly indexed database will have no problem with finding these records out from few millions of other ones. I assume you use not a join table, but a :parent_id in each child. I suspect that a bigger problem may be the size of the edit form (but it depends on the amount of data in each record). Of course the amount of memory, used database, server load and other things may also impact performance.

Comment: Thanks Arsen7. First, I use a join table. For a single parent I will have no more than 400 grandchildren lookups with an average of 50 grandchildren lookups (important point). So the numbers of lookups don't worry me. What worries me is the large child_grandchild join table (though it seems now it might not be much of a problem?). If proper indexing might just do it, then I need to read up on indexing join tables :)
The edit form is about 120kB.  

Will it most likely do (as in; this is most likely premature optimization)

Comment: BTW: The server we're putting this on is this one:
http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF04a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328423.html

I'm in info sec, not a web app developer so I don't have exerience with larger databases with join tables for web apps like this one. Indexing join tables... any good resources out there?